# Record audio, add effects, then save result to a audio file

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, audio-recording, fmod

I am having trouble doing what the title said. My goal is to be able to add any desired effects to your recording, save the modified audio, then send that to a server.

I have searched the fourms and came across these threads:
viewtopic.php?f=7&t=13029&p=45362&hilit=saving#p45362
viewtopic.php?f=7&t=12660&p=44586&hilit=saving#p44586
viewtopic.php?f=7&t=13178&p=45746&hilit=saving#p45746

After reading those, I see it is possible to save the modified audio, but can it only be saved as a wav? Like I said after it is saved it will be sent to a server, so size is a big deal and wavs are relatively big compared to other formats. Ignoring that fact, I tried to implement FMOD_OUTPUTTYPE_WAVWRITER and I cannot get that to work; are there any good examples of using it? I looked though the examples in the library but I didn't see any..

But the basic structure of the app is to record, turn some switches off and on to see what filters you want, preview it, then press a button "Save" that will save it. What would this save function consist of?

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using FMOD_OUTPUTTYPE_WAVWRITER is fairly straight forward, you set the type via System::setOutput, specify the output file via System::init extradriverdata. The extradriverdata should be an absolute path to a writable area of the device such as the documents directory. After you have finished playing, call System::release and the file will be complete.

The other option for recording wave data with effects is by creating a custom DSP and connecting it to the channel playing the recorded data. You will then get regular callbacks giving you float data that you must write out to disk yourself. You can find examples of DSPs and writing wav files in the dsp_custom and recordtodisk examples respectively.

Finally note that FMOD doesn't come with the facility to write compressed audio to disk, you will need another API to achieve this goal.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am going to do as you suggested and try to get it working tomorrow. I think I am just having trouble seeing the structure behind using FMOD.

Comment: What would be the best way to get the .wav file into NSData to store in an object? I want to pass the sound around, and I am trying to figure the best way to do it.

Comment: You can open a .wav with FMOD and use the Sound::lock / Sound::unlock or Sound::readData to access the raw PCM. However if this is the .wav file output by wavwriter, it's probably best to not use that solution, and go with the DSP option instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can save as an AAC file via the ExtAudioFile API.